# PostgreSQL - What does it mean FROM at UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a project and i've seen an sql query that i couldn't understand.

```
    UPDATE 
    table1 
    SET 
    field = TRUE
    FROM 
    table2
    WHERE
    table1.field2 = ... AND
    table2.field3 = ... AND

    ...
```

Does from mean something like join? If so, what is its equivalent query with join statement?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works the same as `SELECT ... FROM ...` and lets you name additional tables that will be joined into the query. Having it available for [`UPDATE ... FROM ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html) is a postgresql extension, not widely supported by other databases. It allows you to update a column with values computed based on joining to other tables. Usually you could get the same results by using as sub-select, but it might be harder to write that way.

Postgres also supports a `RETURNING` clause for `UPDATE` and `INSERT`, which further blurs the line between those and `SELECT`; it lets you get values from an update query. This is quite handy to get back autogenerated primary key IDs and the like...

There are some examples in the postgresql documentation page I linked.